# Table Creation Error

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

Looking to fix the syntax error

**Error Message:**

> force int(9) NOT NULL default '0', perm tinyint(1) NOT NULL default
>   '0', act' at line 11

**My Table Syntax:**

```
CREATE TABLE `ttp_sites` (
siteid int( 4 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
wname char( 64 ) NOT NULL default '',
email char( 64 ) NOT NULL default '',
siteurl char( 255 ) NOT NULL default '',
sitename char( 128 ) NOT NULL default '',
furl char( 255 ) NOT NULL default '',
icqnumb char( 20 ) default '',
icqname char( 20 ) default '',
sent int( 9 ) NOT NULL default '0',
FORCE int( 9 ) NOT NULL default '0',
perm tinyint( 1 ) NOT NULL default '0',
active tinyint( 1 ) NOT NULL default '0',
manage_type tinyint( 1 ) NOT NULL default '0',
send_ratio int( 4 ) NOT NULL default '0',
PRIMARY KEY ( siteid ) ,
KEY siteurl( siteurl ) ,
KEY sitename( sitename ) ,
KEY active( active )
) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT =1;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, check out our [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), copy pasting a bunch of code is not an OK question.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is you have used a **[reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-0.html) FORCE** , you can use the reserve keyword to create a table column name is by giving the name within single quotes which takes the keyword as a name.

```
CREATE TABLE `ttp_sites` (
siteid int( 4 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
wname char( 64 ) NOT NULL default '',
email char( 64 ) NOT NULL default '',
siteurl char( 255 ) NOT NULL default '',
sitename char( 128 ) NOT NULL default '',
furl char( 255 ) NOT NULL default '',
icqnumb char( 20 ) default '',
icqname char( 20 ) default '',
sent int( 9 ) NOT NULL default '0',
`FORCE` int( 9 ) NOT NULL default '0',
perm tinyint( 1 ) NOT NULL default '0',
active tinyint( 1 ) NOT NULL default '0',
manage_type tinyint( 1 ) NOT NULL default '0',
send_ratio int( 4 ) NOT NULL default '0',
PRIMARY KEY ( siteid ) ,
KEY siteurl( siteurl ) ,
KEY sitename( sitename ) ,
KEY active( active )
) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT =1;
```

## [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ebff9)

**P.s :** Don't use keyword for naming a column.

Updated Query of your's in the comment

```
CREATE TABLE ttp_traffic
( siteid int(4) NOT NULL default '0',
 ipaddr char(25) NOT NULL default '',
 click int(3) NOT NULL default '0', 
 prox int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
 refer char(255) NOT NULL default '',
 datev timestamp NOT NULL, 
 KEY siteid (siteid),
 KEY datev (datev),
 KEY click (click), 
 KEY ipaddr (ipaddr) )ENGINE = MYISAM;
```

Timestamp should not have datatype size that was the error in your code

## [SQl Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bed3)

Comment: Now the code don't have error, but under this code I have one more table with another syntax error. I try to change that, but still getting syntax error. What I have to change on that code? I don’t have Idea. There is some syntax error to use near '(10) NOT NULL,
CREATE TABLE `ttp_traffic` (
siteid int(4) NOT NULL default '0',
ipaddr char(25) NOT NULL default '',
click int(3) NOT NULL default '0',
prox int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
refer char(255) NOT NULL default '',
datev timestamp(10) NOT NULL,
KEY siteid (siteid),
KEY datev (datev),
KEY click (click),
KEY ipaddr (ipaddr)
)ENGINE = MYISAM;